# How to install Neo4j on FreeBSD?

Tags: neo4j, freebsd

Has anyone succeeded in installed Neo4j on FreeBSD?

The following works (edit 28 July 2015):

```
# pkg install bash        # requirement, skip if already installed
# pkg install openjdk     # requirement, skip if already installed
# pkg install lsof
# adduser neo4j
# su neo4j                # make sure you set bash as the default shell
# wget http://neo4j.com/artifact.php?name=neo4j-community-2.1.5-unix.tar.gz -o neo4j-project.tar.gz
# tar xvzf neo4j-project
# modify ./neo4j-project/bin/utils script to use /usr/local/bin/bash instead of /bin/bash
# modify ./neo4j-project/conf/neo4j-server-properties to your needs
# neo4j ./neo4j-project/bin/neo4j console
```

Comment: This sounds like a question for SuperUser...

Comment: found a [posting](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/K1-veCmdD6o) that seems to have it working.

Comment: Great!  Consider "Answering" your own question if it works!

Comment: I tested this with Neo4j 2.2.3 (neo4j-community-2.2.3-unix). It works like a charm. I only had to change the ./bin/utils script to /usr/local/bin/bash instead of /bin/bash. I started the server with the following command: './bin/neo4j console' because the command './bin/neo4j start' did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Copied from @rvaneiik's google groups [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/K1-veCmdD6o) (in the comments).</sub>

---

Had the same issue and I found that creating a dedicated neo4j user with bash as shell resolves it.
The steps I did to get Neo4J 2.0.1 running:

```
pkg install bash
pkg install openjdk
pkg install lsof
```

Modify both the `neo4j` and `utils` script to use `/usr/local/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/bash`

```
su to neo4j user
cd bin
./neo4j start
```

Haven't found any issues yet, the setup is currently only used for testing though.

Comment: Does anyone know whether a package will be maintained in the ports tree?